# Java : Quartz scheduler - is there a way I can get next five runs of a scheduled job

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz

Is there any API which gives the next n runs of a cron expression.

Comment: Do you mean, given a cron expression and a job, schedule it N times?

Answer (score 2):

Quartz jobs are scheduled using a Trigger (`org.quartz.Trigger`). The trigger interface exposes two useful methods:

```
Date getNextFireTime();
Date getFireTimeAfter(Date afterTime);
```

So, take your Trigger, call `getNextFireTime()`. Now you know when it'll fire next. Then call `getFireTimeAfter( next )` and pass it in the next fire time. Repeat until you have enough run times for your use case.

So, for five runs, something like this should work:

```
List<Date> getNextFiveRuns(Trigger trigger) {
    List<Date> runs = new ArrayList<>();
    Date next = trigger.getNextFireTime();

    // check for null, which indicates a non-repeating trigger or one with an end-time
    while(next != null && runs.size() < 5) {
      runs.add(next);
      next = trigger.getFireTimeAfter(next);
    }
    return runs;
}
```

Quartz 2.3.0 JavaDoc: [org.quartz.Trigger](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/Trigger.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate next run times like this:

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.SimpleTriggerContext;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger("0 0 10 * * ?");
    SimpleTriggerContext triggerContext = new SimpleTriggerContext();
    Date testDate = new Date();
    int i = 0;
    while (i++ < 5) {
        triggerContext.update(null, null, testDate);
        testDate = trigger.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
        System.out.println(testDate);
    }
}
```

And output is:

```
    Wed Jun 05 10:00:00 CEST 2019
    Thu Jun 06 10:00:00 CEST 2019
    Fri Jun 07 10:00:00 CEST 2019
    Sat Jun 08 10:00:00 CEST 2019
    Sun Jun 09 10:00:00 CEST 2019
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to just understand, you can use http://www.cronmaker.com/ to calculate the next few scheduled run times

Looks like cronmaker has an API as well(I see you have mentioned you are looking for API) :

```
curl http://www.cronmaker.com/rest/sampler?expression={expression}
```

Example:

```
curl http://www.cronmaker.com/rest/sampler?expression=0 0/2 * 1/1 * ? *&hour=13&minute=45
```

Source:

http://www.cronmaker.com/help/rest-api-help.html

Comment: Using an external service takes time, resources and is error prone