# How to get the quartz getNextFiretime (Java)

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am working on my automation project where I need trigger some functionality for every 8 hours to see if the expected web element is displayed. I am using the quartz scheduler to trigger the functionality for every 8 hours.

When I run the code,  the nextfireTime is displayed for the 1st iteration. once the first iteration is completed, the code is waiting for the next iteration. But the  time is not printed in the log. How can do that?

```
StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
JobDetail Job1 = JobBuilder.newJob(myJob.class).build();
Trigger t1 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("cronTrigger1","group1").withSchedule(CronSchedulerBuilder.cronSchedule ("0/3 0 0 ? * * *)).build();
while (!elementtext.contains("***************"))
{
    Date Currenttime = new Date();
    Date date = scheduler.schedulejob(job1,t1);
    scheduler.start();
    log.info(job1.key() + will run at  : +t1.getNextFiretime());
    }
    if (elementtext.contains("**********")){
        scheduler.shutdown();
    }
```

I expect the time to be displayed after the 1st run. But it is not displayed.

Comment: Check this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451154/java-quartz-scheduler-is-there-a-way-i-can-get-next-five-runs-of-a-scheduled/56451393#56451393